# ASP.NET - designer

Tags: asp.net, designer, visual-studio-2010

I'm using the ASP.NET designer in Visual Studio 2010. How do I change the layout of the page horizontally as well as vertically? I'm used to working in the WPF designer where you could just drag and lay out how you like, but the ASP.NET designer doesn't seem to want to allow me to move controls horizontally- like the page MUST be laid out from the top left. it'll only stack controls one after another in the line. I also can't seem to resize tags to be smaller from the left or top.

Comment: AFAIK you're out of luck, unless there's an extension that makes WPF-like designer behavior possible in the ASP.NET designer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WPF Layout is based on control a position, `x` and `y` in a Grid.

In ASP.NET (Web stuff) you are working without a virtual grid, all is done in a white page where you can start writing from top to bottom, from left to right.

To Control that position you can always accomplish it via CSS, just check the details on your control and add to the `style`

```
position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 30px;
```

Though it's a bad programming line, if you go that way.

Position in a web environment should always be set as an external CSS file so you can separate what's the elements and what is the design.

If you don't like this at all, you can always buy and use [http://www.**visualwebgui**.com](http://www.visualwebgui.com) to use WinForms alike as WebPages.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a good horizontal/vertical layout system in CSS, I recommend the [960 Grid System](http://960.gs/). I've used it on projects before with great success. It takes a bit of getting used to, but the end result is a lot of fine control over your layouts.

Comment: Of course, of course. 960 GS is a CSS framework that just helps with layout. I can say from experience that any site you build will need a lot more CSS than this framework provides. It's just nice to not have to reinvent the wheel, plus it's a helpful way to communicate with designers.